# Google Analitics Measurement Protocol - how to split e-commerce payload?

Tags: post, google-analytics, get, e-commerce, measurement-protocol

I have problem with Enhanced E-commerce Measurement Protocol ( [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#enhanced-ecomm) ). Sometimes client is buying about 100 different products in one transaction. It exceedes the size of 8192 bytes ( [reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#using-post) ) and request doesn't go through.

I tried to split that into small packs with:

- transaction details + one item with index 1 (all items as pr1id)

I tried also to split that with increment index:

- transaction details + one item with incrementing index (for ex. first I send transaction + pr1id, then transaction + pr2id etc)

I always end up with only one item in google analytics. Is there any way to split it in working and correct way? I couldn't find solution in google or docs.

Comment: What kind of ecommerce is that where a client buys hundreds of different skus in a single transaction?

Comment: I dont think its relevant to the problem..